# How to get react checkbox value

Tags: reactjs, button, checkbox

I am building a simple password generator where the user clicks on a 'submit' button and is displayed a password based on which input checkboxes are ticked.

I currently have 4 pieces of state for each checkbox, and a simple input file that returns a simple input with a checkbox. I call this input file with each of their state as a prop as well as an event handler that they all use.

So i am currently stuck on how to see which input checkboxes are ticked and which are not... when i try to see this it is either they are all ticked, or they are all false (even when checkbox 1 and 2 are false and checkbox 3 and 4 are true).

I am a bit confused as to why this isnt working... any help?

Please let me know if you want me to provide some code to help better understand

Comment: Hi, a sample of the existing component/ components would be helpful here to figure out where things are going wrong. I can answer with that additional context

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your state in an object, and update its values on change like:

```
export default function App() {
  const [conditions, setConditions] = useState({
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false,
    d: false,
  });

  function handleChange(key) {
    setConditions((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: !prev[key] }));
  }

  function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    generatePassword(conditions);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {Object.entries(conditions).map(([key, value]) => (
        <label key={key}>
          {key}
          <input
            checked={conditions[key]}
            onChange={() => handleChange(key)}
            type="checkbox"
          />
        </label>
      ))}
      <button>Generate</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function generatePassword({ a, b, c, d }) {
  console.log("Generating password with the following params", { a, b, c, d });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store the 4 checkboxes in an object like below

```
    const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    lowercase: true,
    uppercase: true,
    numbers: true,
    specialChars: true,
  });
```

and now write an onChange function for handling clicks :

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
const { name } = event.target;
setOptions((prevOptions) => ({
  ...prevOptions,
  [name]: !prevOptions[name],
}));
```

};

You can log the option state to see which checkboxes are checked. :)

Visit this link for more :
https://dev.to/collegewap/how-to-work-with-checkboxes-in-react-44bc

or look at this [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/optimistic-mountain-hmlt46?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0006356iy6s5yflz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0002356io0zzylla%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0003356i06z710l2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0005356inytuc6li%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqpze2el0002356io0zzylla%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0001356i8tkhqq20%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpzg5xs005o356iw2k14x6g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A2%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A7%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A55%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpzzo880002356i6n9q4b38%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A21%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A5%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A21%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FMultipleCheckboxes.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0002356io0zzylla%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqpzzo880002356i6n9q4b38%2522%257D%252C%2522clqpze2el0005356inytuc6li%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0004356ifchym134%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0005356inytuc6li%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0004356ifchym134%2522%257D%252C%2522clqpze2el0003356i06z710l2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqpze2el0003356i06z710l2%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).